# CS0201: Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I keep receiving the above error on the following line of code:

```
<select 
 id="buildingSlctRoom@{Model.roomNo;}Request@{Model.RequestNo;}" 
 class="form-control" 
 onchange="fillRooms(@{Model.roomNo;},@{Model.RequestNo;},$('#buildingsslctRoom@{Model.roomNo;}Request@{Model.RequestNo;}').val())" 
 style="width:auto;">
```

I cant see anything that could be causing this from that code?

Any ideas?

Thanks

class containing roomNo and RequestNo

```
    namespace Timetabling06.ModelViews
    {
         public class roomCheckerObject
         {
              public string code { get; set; }
              public ICollection<room> rooms { get; set; }  
              public ICollection<room> deptRooms { get; set; }
              public ICollection<building> buildings { get; set; }
              public int roomNo { get; set; }
              public int RequestNo { get; set; }
         }
     }
```

Code that sets object variables :

```
public ActionResult _roomChecker(int roomNum, int requestNum, String user, int roundID, int day, int time, int length,int[] weeks,int students,String roomType,String park, String[] facilities){
        var rooms = db.rooms.Include(r=>r.building).Include(r=>r.facilities);
        rooms = rooms.Where(r => r.capacity >= students);
        if(roomType != "Any"){
            rooms = rooms.Where(r=>r.roomType.Equals(roomType));
        }
        if (park != "Any") { 
            rooms = rooms.Where(r=>r.building.park.Equals(park));
        }

        if (facilities != null)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < facilities.Length; i++)
            {
                rooms = rooms.Where(r => r.facilities.Any(f => f.facilityName.Equals(facilities[i])));

            }
        }

        var deptRooms = db.rooms.Include(r => r.building).Include(r => r.facilities).Where(r=>r.belongsTo.Equals(user));

        roomCheckerObject suitableRooms = new roomCheckerObject();
        suitableRooms.code = user;
        suitableRooms.roomNo = roomNum;
        suitableRooms.RequestNo = requestNum;
        if(rooms.Count() >0){
            suitableRooms.rooms = rooms.ToList();
            var buildings = rooms.Select(r => r.building).Distinct();
            suitableRooms.buildings = buildings.ToList();
        }


        if(deptRooms.Count() >0){
            suitableRooms.deptRooms = deptRooms.ToList();
        }
        return PartialView(suitableRooms);
    }
```

Comment: What is declaration of Model.RequestNo & Model.roomNo & Model.RequestNo ?

Comment: @Jacek added more code above ^^

Comment: I recommend you to read about name convension in c# about naming vars, classes and method. It will make your code more readable in future

Comment: @Jacek I will do, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to write razor code inside html, but your way of writing is not correct.

For writing razor code inside html,you need do this way:

```
<select 
id="buildingSlctRoom@(Model.roomNo)Request@(Model.RequestNo)" 
class="form-control" 
onchange="fillRooms('@Model.roomNo','@Model.RequestNo',$('#buildingsslctRoom@(Model.roomNo)Request@(Model.RequestNo)').val())" 
style="width:auto;">
```

Answer (score 2):

```
@{Model.RequestNo;},$('#buildingsslctRoom@{Model.roomNo;}
```

change this code to this

```
@Model.RequestNo,$('#buildingsslctRoom@Model.roomNo
```

remove {} char, this is for execute code, not for use value. Ot should resolve your problem.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. I keep doing this and wondering why I had the error. Razor and ASP newbie haha

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `@{Model.roomNo;}` is evaluated as a command. And it will give you your exception because it's neither method call nor property assignment (as written in exception).

If you want just output value of `@( Model.roomNo)`